# This recipient does not accept payments denominated in INR

Tags: paypal

I am integrating the Paypal payment gateway using a Paypal sandbox account (in India).
Everything is working fine: the URL is building properly and redirecting to the Paypal sandbox account and it's login successfully. However, after login it gives me the following error when I am trying to pay:

> This recipient does not accept payments denominated in INR. Please contact the seller and ask him to update his Payment Receiving Preferences to accept this currency.

If I pay in USD currency, it gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could show the code where it fails

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered from the same problem at same time as yours; it's my personal thinking that it might happened due to some economic changes in India. If you are making project for Indian public, then my advice is to go for some other payment integration options like Instamojo, Razorpay. They are doing far better than paypal.